# .size in STM32f091XX startup file

Tags: arm, stm32, embedded-linux, cortex-m

I was going through a startup file of ARM cortex M0 STM32f091 controller and came across this:

```
.size __HeapBase, . - __HeapBase
```

What is `.size` used for? What does the syntax, given the above perform?

Comment: This is specific to a certain compiler tool chain. Please specify which one you are using or the question cannot be answered.